# Setting up a default log when Logger not found in Log4Net

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net

I am using Log4Net as the logging mechanism for an application of ours. Our configuration is contained in a config file and in our code we programatically invoke which of our several loggers (mostly using `FileAppenders`) we want to invoke. Recently I realized that one of our log files was not being populated, and I tracked it down to a string mismatch, between the name in our configuration file and the name we were programatically invoking in our code. Because the `LogManager` could not find the specified logger the root was returned, which for our config is not setup to meaningfully log anywhere.

My question is, is there a way to setup log4net to allow for using specific `logger`s, but that will fall back to a general `logger` if the specified `logger` is not found?

For example using a configuration file like this

```xml
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
</configSections>

<log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>

    <logger name="TestFileLogger">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="TestFileAppender" />
    </logger>

    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p [%x] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="TestFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="TestLog" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyyMMdd&quot;.log&quot;" />
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
    </appender>

</log4net>
</configuration>
```

And invoking the loggers in C# like this

```
var fileLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("TestFileLogger");
fileLogger.Info("This logs appropriately.");

var bogusLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("Bogus");
bogusLogger.Info("This should go to a general log. Bogus is not a recognized appender");
```

Is there a good way to log the messages from `bogusLogger` to some kind of general log file? My initial thought was to create a general file appender that is part of the root node, but this is very noisy as ALL log messages will be routed to this file. Is there a way to ONLY route messages that are not captured in another log file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [LogManager.Exists("Bogus")](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.LogManager.Exists_overloads.html) to determine if the bogus-logger or your default implementation should be used.

You could create an extensionmethod on LogManager that could handle it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! `LogManager.Exists` is a great way to actually figure out if the logger actually exists, as `LogManager.GetLogger` will always return the `root` if the specified logger is not found. Small note: `LogManager` is static and therefore can't have an extension method, but a wrapper class works great!